# SQL Server - normalization / query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to query a data set and am concerned my data isn't normalized enough.

I have 2 tables: one that deals with question details and the other with the answers users have provided to the questions.  For example:

Table 1 (Question details: 200 records)
Fld1: 'Question ID' 
Fld2: 'Question Header' (value e.g., 'what is your favorite color?'
Fld3: 'Question Details' 'colors can range from the ultraviolet spectrum'... or

Other questions may relate to colors in different ways.

Table 2 (Questions: thousands of records)
Fld1: 'User'
Fld2: 'Q1' - foreign key to tbl1.fld1.'Question ID' (value is 'yes' or 'no') 
Fld3: [Q2] different question, also a foreign key to tbl1.'Question ID'...
(188 more Q fields, each linked to tbl1.[Question ID]...

I'm having trouble querying, e.g., 'give me all users that answered 'yes' to questions that have to do with colors'.

I can do this in multi-parts, e.g.,

```
select [Question ID] from tbl1 where [Question Details] like '%color%'
```

Say the result set returns Q3, Q5, Q8.  I can then run:

```
select user from tbl2 where Q3 like 'yes' OR Q5 like 'yes' OR Q8 like 'yes'
```

I know there's got to be a better way.  Thanks!

Comment: If you could post some actual ddl this would be a lot easier. I am having a hard time deciphering the partial text explanations of your tables. sqlfiddle.com would be a good choice.

Comment: You should be joining the two tables in a single query; that's what foreign keys are for.    Well, it's one thing they're for anyway.